# Multiple entry Schengen visa: Documents required at Immigration/Border control during second visit

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, multiple-entry, cdg

I am an Indian passport holder having residence permit and working in Kuwait, I received a 90 days multiple-entry Schengen C visa issued by German embassy Kuwait for a business purpose. I successfully had my business trip to Germany and returned to Kuwait. I am planning to visit Paris during my holidays as my multiple entry visa is still valid.

**What all documents should I produce at the Immigration and Border crossing at CDG**, as my Visa was issued for business visa by Germany and this will be a tourism purpose which was not mentioned in my visa application. Hotel reservation and itinerary is necessary ? What all questions can I expect?

Comment: Mostly the same documents that you would use to apply for a tourist visa, i.e. bank statements, salary slips, proof that you have a reason to depart the Schengen area (such as your employment), onward/return tickets, etc. But you do not need to show any of these documents unless the border officer asks for them.

Answer (score 4):

In principle, you can be asked pretty much everything, to establish that you have a valid purpose of stay and fulfil all the other conditions (financial means, intent to leave the area, etc.). So hotel booking, itinerary, etc. and, as Michael explained, everything you would need for a fresh visa application might come in handy.

But that's not specific to the second trip, it was also the case for your first trip. In practice, the fact that you are entering France on a German visa could prompt border guards to inquire a bit more than usual but on the other hand having a multiple-entry visa that you have already used is a plus so I would not generally expect many questions.

You also need to have a valid travel health insurance (you only had to prove you had insurance for the first trip when applying for the visa but you are required to be covered for each subsequent trip as well). I have never heard anyone tell me they actually had to prove that, but that's a requirement nonetheless.

Comment: Hi, how can i prove my intention to leave the area ? i have a valid health insurance covering the dates but it is valid only for Germany.

Comment: @clintchristopher The way you prove your intention to leave the area is by showing that you have a stable situation to return to in your country of residence (a job, a stable income, a family, a house, etc.) But that's something you already had to establish when you got the visa in the first place. Also, the fact that you already used the visa is a big plus for you, as it means you already had an occasion to remain illegally in the area but you chose not to. So that's not likely to come up but I mention it to explain that border guards are perfectly allowed to ask about that if they want to.

Comment: Technically, your health insurance is a problem. Like I said, you are not very likely to be asked about it but if border guards do ask and you cannot show you are insured for France, they could (should?) in principle revoke the visa. If possible, they might also allow you to purchase extra insurance on the spot or maybe let it slip but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: hello, as it seems like perfect to keep all the documents necessary for a new visa. i shall keep my return tickets, the copy of the 6 months bank statement(issued on june for the visa), letter issued to prove my employment issued for German embassy,in my passport there is certified that i have residence in Kuwait till 2017,  new insurance, hostel booking, simple literary found in internet.

Comment: the bank statement was issued in june because i applied for visa at that time. in case they ask to show how much money i have for my 7 days trip, how much Euros should i have in hand at that time ?